# How do I reinstate an empty http.config file?

Tags: server, apache2

I stupidly managed somehow to mess up my Apache https.file (I think). I was trying to install a new virtual server using Webmin. I tried using Virtualmin and somehow, it did something to Apache as it won't restart with the following error message:

```
    Failed to start apache :
 * Starting web server apache2
[Fri Feb 07 15:13:37 2020] [warn] NameVirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Fri Feb 07 15:13:37 2020] [warn] NameVirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx has no VirtualHosts
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
   ...fail!
```

I deleted the virtual host but still no luck. I checked my httpd.conf file and it is empty. After trying again to set up a new virtual host the httpd.conf file is missing altogether.

I now need to figure out how to get Apache running again. Can I remove and delete Apache and then reinstall it? Will that generate a new http.conf file which will at least have something in it that I can edit and get Apache to start up again?

Aplogies if this all sounds basic but I haven't had to do much to my server for many years and now tinkering with it has left me high and dry.

Answer (score 0):

The `NameVirtualHost ... has no VirtualHosts` error typically happens when the `.conf` files are incomplete. A common issue that I see is that ports are excluded from the `<VirtualHost>` tag.

Check the various `.conf` files that exist in `/etc/apache/sites-enabled` and look at the `<VirtualHost>` tag. If you see any that match one of these patterns:

- `<VirtualHost>`
- `<VirtualHost *>`
- `<VirtualHost 80>`

Change it to:

|  | Situation |
| --- | --- |
| `<VirtualHost *:80>` | Non-HTTPS Traffic (This will probably consist only of redirects) |
| `<VirtualHost *:443>` | HTTPS-enabled Traffic (This will require an SSL certificate definition) |

Almost a year has passed since you've asked the question, so you've likely solved the issue by now. That said, I do hope this helps anyone in the future who has the same problem.